# Could not connect to Oracle using PDO

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have these snippets but I still cannot connect to my Oracle DB. I believe I did everything right but i don't know where the pitfall is.

```
try {
    $user='weltesadmin'; // Enter your DB User Name.
    $pass='weltespass'; // Enter your DB Password.
    $dataBaseName='weltes'; // Enter your Database Name.
    $dbh = new PDO('OCI:dbname='.$dataBaseName.'charset=UTF-8', $user,$pass);
    echo "Connection Successful";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . " ";
    die();
}
```

And on the `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

Comment: @EduardoVerdugoCáceres now its saying, SQLSTATE[42S02]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:635)

Comment: Check my answer to know your installed drivers and there's no error message??

Answer (score 1):

Check your installed drivers and see if `oci` is installed:

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '\n';
```

If `oci` don't shown, then need to install it (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php)

Comment: oci did show but the problem is i am still getting this error.
`pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12521: TNS:listener does not currently know of instance requested in connect descriptor (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:635)`
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line:

$dbh = new PDO('OCI:dbname='.$dataBaseName.'charset=UTF-8', $user,$pass);

You have used OCI in caps replace that with "oci" (small case) 

(A mistake I had made myself)

Once you change that uncommenting below line from php.ini is sufficient:

extension=php_pdo_oci.dll

Answer (score -1):

My problem solved by following instructions on 
http://lacot.org/blog/2009/11/03/ubuntu-php5-oci8-and-pdo_oci-the-perfect-install.html

Do not forget to export oracle home .Even though oracle home was set i was not able to configure pdo_oci. So give 
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/instantclient_10_2/
before running configure in pdo_oci-1.0 directory

1. enabling the above extensions
2. adding this to requirements.php

   ```
   array(
               'name' => 'PDO Oracle extension',
               'mandatory' => false,
               'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_oci'),
               'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
               'memo' => 'Required for Oracle database.',
   ),
   ```
3. editing dsn in  db.php as follows

   ```
   return [
           'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
           'dsn'=> 'oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=x.y.z.a)(PROTOCOL=tcp)(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=YOURSID)))',
           'username' => 'USER',
           'password' => 'PASS',
           'charset' => 'utf8',
   ];
   ```