# Connect PDO with Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I am new to Oracle, installed the Oracle today the 11g Express Edition.
Then I installed Java SDK, and then the free Oracle SQL Developer.
I connected with system account and created a username and table as defined below. I don't exactly know how Oracle works, I think instead of database name, usernames are used. So below are details.

Username/Connection/Database = `CustomSearch`
Table = `Reservation_General_2`

There are some columns inside that table and some data. but the point is I cant connect to Oracle Server.

Here is how I tried to connect to database server.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: HaiderHassan
 * Date: 9/3/14
 * Time: 9:52 PM
 */
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$tns = "
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
       ";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, 'customsearch', 'babaji');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Problem is when I try to open that page, I get this error.

> ERROR: could not find driver

These are my connection settings when I connect from `Oracle Sql Developer`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, what steps should I take to fix this issue?

### Update

I added the driver by removing semicolon from the `php.ini` file

```
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

But I started getting this error.

> The program can't start because OCI.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I have to click 4 time OK for different alert boxes that shows up. I also downloaded `oci.dll` and copied it to the `windows/system32`, but still getting this error. What to do?

### Update

I uninstalled XAMPP and followed this guide to install Apache and PHP separately,

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html
```

and then I tried my luck. That driver Problem went away but there is new problem

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12521: TNS:listener does not currently know of instance requested in connect descriptor (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:635)

Here below is my new connection String.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/xe/ORCL', 'customsearch', 'babaji');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried to follow this answer on Stack Overflow for making a connection string.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970261/connect-oracle-with-pdo-with-sid-and-instance-name
```

### Update 2

Also tried to check if drivers installed. I used this code

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '\n';
```

Got this code from this below link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239433/could-not-connect-to-oracle-using-pdo
```

it echoes this below line

```
oci\n
```

So this means that it is installed or this means some drivers are missing?

### Update 3

Again rolled back to old connection just changed some stuff in that connection and seems like connection to oracle worked.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, 'customsearch', 'babaji');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to database';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

with this I get the message 'Connected to database', means echo works because there is no error given by PDO.

But problem is now my query is not working? What happened to my query? Or will I have to change the syntax of the query also as I connected to Oracle? Or is the connection still not working?

Comment: Er... You don't install Oracle Instant Client by copying `oci.dll` to `C:\Windows`. Get the complete package from Oracle and follow the instructions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
Can you please provide me the link to the complete package, so i can download and try to fix this problem.

Comment: You can get it from here: [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.google.es/search?q=oracle+instant+client&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=R4UNVJCnHuuA8Qf3lICgAw)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
i already have installed instantclient_12_1 as it was asked in tut, Also updated my Qustion, should i uninstall and install and another version of instant client?

Comment: I thought it was clear you already had the appropriate PDO driver installed and you only had to get Instant Client working. I'm unsure of what advice to offer now...

Answer (score 12):

Check PDO and OCI drivers installed properly or not

Try with following code

```
class PDOConnection {

    private $dbh;

    function __construct() {
        try {

            $server         = "127.0.0.1";
            $db_username    = "SYSTEM";
            $db_password    = "Oracle_1";
            $service_name   = "ORCL";
            $sid            = "ORCL";
            $port           = 1521;
            $dbtns          = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = $service_name) (SID = $sid)))";

            //$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".dbname, $db_username, $db_password);

            $this->dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $dbtns . ";charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function select($sql) {
        $sql_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sql_stmt->execute();
        $result = $sql_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }

    public function insert($sql) {
        $sql_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        try {
            $result = $sql_stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            trigger_error('Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        if ($result) {
            return $sql_stmt->rowCount();
        }
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->dbh = NULL;
    }

}

$dbh = new PDOConnection();

$dbh->select($select_sql);
$dbh->insert($insert_sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the PDO driver? Look at the output of `phpinfo()` to see what's installed and/or enabled in your environment.

[PDO Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)

If you're running PHP on linux, you can see what PDO drivers are available for your distribution by running `yum list php-pdo`. You can install the driver by running `yum install php-pdo`. You may also need to install a database specific driver for your database. Running a `yum list php*` will show you all the PHP extensions available for installation.

[Database Specific Drivers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php)

Comment: Thankyou for reply, 
Ok, i added the driver by removing semicolon from the php.ini
`extension=php_pdo_oci.dll`
But i started getting this error.

`The program can't start because OCI.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`
i have to click 4 time OK for different alert boxes that shows up.
i also downloaded oci.dll and copied it to the windows/system32, but still getting this error. 
What to do?

Comment: Windows being windows, you might have to restart the server for configuration changes to take effect. Try rebooting if you're certain you have the drivers downloaded and installed in the correct location. As it is, clearly it cannot see/find the driver. And of course, read the instructions for windows installations in the PHP manual to make sure you've done everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install instant client on Windows, I used it and it work, see this video, the only that change is in the video when he execute install, you don't have to because in the new zip, doesn't have the execution file. I only have a problem when I make a SELECT query but the connection works just fine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZDDI9HFBIU

Contact me if you have any question

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with oracle listener configuration, your driver is ok, the error "listener does not currently know of inst.." means there is oracle configuration issue. You must ensure that the parameters in the listener file is exactly the same as in the connection string.

Also your connection string oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/xe/ORCL is incorrect, it should be oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/orcl (host:port/service_name) as indicated in listener.ora file. Ensure the correctness of your connection string using SQL developer.

you may check the below link, this link illustrates the matching of listener.ora and connection string parameters and there is php pdo code snippet at the end with the correct usage of the connection string.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMQXVihgrrE

https://adhoctuts.com/fix-oracle-io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-error/

Answer (score -2):

Wrong, Wrong & Wrong.

PHPinfo() will NOT enable the PDO driver nor will it show up.

You do NOT need to download a PDO driver separately the one packaged with your PHP installation will work fine.

You do NOT need to install the instant client as your PHP for windows will have the instant client built-in.

Solution:
Updating IIS7 with PHP manager or updating the PHP ini file within your installation to Enable the DLL.

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
[PHP_PDO_OCI]
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

Comment: PDO is not being deprecated.

Comment: take a look @ page 29 from the manual

"The PDO extension and PDO_OCI driver are open source and included in PHP 5.1 onwards. Oracle does not contribute to PDO_OCI.

The PHP community has let the PDO project languish and Oracle recommends using OCI8 instead whenever possible because of its better feature set, performance, reliability and stability. Use of PDO_OCI for general purpose applications is not recommended."

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf

Comment: Take a look at the date on that book.  Things change and Oracle does now contribute to PDO_OCI.  It's not being deprecated.

Comment: okay maybe the source is outdated but why the downvote? answer is correct as long as your reference the correct DLLs all is well