# XAMPP access the database from another computer

Tags: php, oracle, xampp

I have 2 server/pc. In PC 1 I installed the XAMPP and in PC 2 this is where my database is installed. I am using Oracle Database 9i (very old version) on PC 2 and on PC 1 I am using PHP 7.3.9. I already enabled the extension for oracle (pdo_oci.dll).

Here is my database connection code:

```
new PDO('oci:dbname=backend;host=192.168.10.30;', 'sa', 'backendpass');
```

**192.168.10.30** - is where the database is installed.

Is there a way to access database from PC 1 to PC 2?

Comment: I think there is nothing to do in xampp side. Make sure your codein php to connect db is correct. It will work. Also you can add your pc2 ip address in pc1 host address (but this is only optional step)

Comment: @Gopipuli What is the correct connection code? The code is used is the same code I used when I installed xampp on PC 2 I just modified it a little

Comment: I dont know much about orcle db since I worked in mysql,sql, domino etc. Anyway I found these links which may help you
http://www.learn-coding.today/php_pdo_oracle.php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712045/connect-pdo-with-oracle-database/52071713 good luck

Comment: The OCI DSN format is defined here ~ https://www.php.net/manual/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php. Have you tried `new PDO("oci:dbname=//192.168.10.30:1512/backend", "sa", "backendpass")`?