# PHP connection string to remote database ORA-12154

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, oracle9i

I have 2 computers:
**PC 1** - Here is where I installed the XAMPP.
**PC 2** - Here is where my database which is Oracle 9i is installed.

I am using PHP 7 and already added **PDO_OCI** extension.

Here is my connection string:

```
define("DB_HOST", "192.168.10.30:1521");
define("DB_NAME", "BACKEND");
define("DB_USER", "sa");
define("DB_PASS", "sa_backend");

new PDO('oci:dbname='. DB_NAME . ';host='. DB_HOST .';', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

When I used this code I am getting this error:

> Warning: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:709)

**UPDATE 1**

```
$server         = "192.168.10.30";
$db_username    = "sa";
$db_password    = "sa_backend";
$service_name   = "backend";
$sid            = "backend";
$port           = 1521;
$dbtns          = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = $service_name) (SERVER = SHARED) (SID = $sid)))";

$this->dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $dbtns . ";charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

I used this code I found on other stackoverflow link. Now I am getting this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12520: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:728)

I tried to updated the process to 200 even to 400 but the error is still the same.

Comment: This question is eerily similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674241/xampp-access-the-database-from-another-computer) (same Oracle version, same IP address, same DB name... creepy). In any case, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674241/xampp-access-the-database-from-another-computer#comment114354298_64674241)

Comment: @Phil I tried it but here is the new error SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:728)

Comment: Please update the code in your question to show what you tried

Comment: I think you should read that comment I linked to again. I'm not saying it will definitely work but you could at least try the format used in the PHP manual

Comment: Try this connection string  `"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SID = $sid)))"`  and then  try this connection string  `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = $service_name) ))`

Comment: You may find it easier to use an alias from a tnsnames.ora file, where the file has the full string.  Also see https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/

Comment: @DmitryDemin I tried it but here is the error `ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported` is there a version where it is still supported or is there a work around?

Comment: You need to install 11.2.0.4 oracle client for oracle 9i

Comment: @DmitryDemin where do I install it on the db server?

Comment: This is client. Only Oracle client 11.2.0.4 can connect to oracle server 9i. Or upgrade your server to 11 or 19 version.

Comment: @DmitryDemin is Oracle client 11.2.0.4 instant client?

Comment: @lawrenceagulto You can use any type client.